# Pattern validation Specific HTML

Tags: html, regex

I need to do the following: in an input text you will be forced to write 3 decimal numbers separated by (,) maximum 3 (,) and that only one "." for each number EXAMPLE:

100.10,100.20,100.30

I have tried it like this:

`pattern="([0-9]{,1}[,])([0-9]{,1}[,])([0-9]{,1})"`

Comment: This worked for me, but it doesn't let me put the default value which is 0,0,0:

`pattern="([0-9])+.{1}([0-9])+,([0-9])+.{1}([0-9])+,([0-9])+.{1}([0-9])+"`

Answer (score 1):

You can start with matching a number with an optional decimal part, and then repeat that same pattern 2 times preceded with a comma.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally, and the comma by itself does not have to be in a character class.

You can write the pattern as:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?){2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part starting with a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a comma, 1+ digits and again an optional decimal parts
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat 2 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVUbGD/1)

If in Javascript, the pattern attribute is anchored implicitly:

```
pattern="\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?){2}"
```